# Login / Create an account with an ID

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, account

Whenever a user creates an account, I want their ID to increase by 1, so we have something like this:

> User 1 >> ID
>   User 2 >> ID 1 more than previous.
>   User 3 >> ID 1 more than previous.
>   User 4 >> ID 1 more than previous.

So how can I make this in PHP and a MySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

On database side create a table to save the users with a field `id` as integer

[PRIMARY KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-primary-key.html), 
[AUTOINCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

and if you want you can also define it as [UNSIGNED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html) (this way the field can be only positive)

this way it will be done automatically when you insert a row into the database...

Example Query Insert:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,username,password) 
 values (,'UsernameSelected','PasswordSelected');
```

Comment: best if you flag it as unsigned as well: `id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment`

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)`

Answer (score 0):

Set the Id field as [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). You can follow this tutorial to set it using phpmyadmin: [tutorial](http://www.reg.ca/faq/PhpMyAdminTutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind what will happen if a user is deleted. If your goal is to always have user001 through user100 to be filled, I don't believe incrementing by 1 alone won't solve your issue. You'll have to do a check to see what "spots are open" between the lowest number and highest number. If there's one or more, those will have to be filled first and only when there are none, would you take the highest number and continue adding 1.

Just a thought.